# Why does my C++ solution to the "Fish" challange by codility fail?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting Codility fish challange which is described as follows:

> You are given two non-empty arrays A and B consisting of N integers.
>   Arrays A and B represent N voracious fish in a river, ordered
>   downstream along the flow of the river.
>
> The fish are numbered from 0 to N − 1. If P and Q are two fish and P <
>   Q, then fish P is initially upstream of fish Q. Initially, each fish
>   has a unique position.
>
> Fish number P is represented by A[P] and B[P]. Array A contains the
>   sizes of the fish. All its elements are unique. Array B contains the
>   directions of the fish. It contains only 0s and/or 1s, where:
>
> 0 represents a fish flowing upstream, 1 represents a fish flowing
>   downstream. If two fish move in opposite directions and there are no
>   other (living) fish between them, they will eventually meet each
>   other. Then only one fish can stay alive − the larger fish eats the
>   smaller one. More precisely, we say that two fish P and Q meet each
>   other when P < Q, B[P] = 1 and B[Q] = 0, and there are no living fish
>   between them. After they meet:
>
> If A[P] > A[Q] then P eats Q, and P will still be flowing downstream,
>   If A[Q] > A[P] then Q eats P, and Q will still be flowing upstream. We
>   assume that all the fish are flowing at the same speed. That is, fish
>   moving in the same direction never meet. The goal is to calculate the
>   number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, consider arrays A and B such that:
>
> A[0] = 4    B[0] = 0   A[1](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/) = 3    B[1](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/) = 1   A[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNfIG.png) = 2    B[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNfIG.png) = 0
>   A[3] = 1    B[3] = 0   A[4] = 5    B[4] = 0 Initially all the fish are
>   alive and all except fish number 1 are moving upstream. Fish number 1
>   meets fish number 2 and eats it, then it meets fish number 3 and eats
>   it too. Finally, it meets fish number 4 and is eaten by it. The
>   remaining two fish, number 0 and 4, never meet and therefore stay
>   alive.
>
> Write a function:
>
> int solution(vector &A, vector &B);
>
> that, given two non-empty arrays A and B consisting of N integers,
>   returns the number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, given the arrays shown above, the function should return
>   2, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000]; each element of
>   array B is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1;
>   the elements of A are all distinct.

My solution is as follows:

```
// you can use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    std::queue<int> downStreamers;
    int deadFish = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)B.size(); i++)
    {
        int direction = B[i];
        int size = A[i];

        if(direction == 1)
            downStreamers.push(size);
        else
        {
            while(!downStreamers.empty()) 
            {
                deadFish += 1;
                if(size > downStreamers.front())
                {  
                    downStreamers.pop();
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return A.size()-deadFish;

}
```

Here is how I designed this code (in my head):

Queue structure called downStreamers will contain fish going in the downstream direction (1)

deadFish will contain counter of deaths that occur due to direction collision

The Loop:

For every fish i

- check if i fish is going downstream (1), if so add the size of the said
  fish at the back of the downStreamers queue.
- given that the ith fish is going upstream (0), I want to increase the deadFish counter given that the queue is not empty. If the fish get's defeated by downStreamers stack, simply exit the loop, else pop the fish from the downStreamers untill it's empty.

At the end of the loop, the result should be the number of fishes (A.size()) - deadFishes. This works for simple test cases. However, it fails the hidden ones and codility doesn't provide much feedback as to what went wrong.

Here are my testing results.

[image]

I'd appreciate if someone would provide me with the insight into how approach these problems in a fool-proof manner.

Comment: Can you add the challenge description to the question?

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem with your code is using a queue. I think it is going to work, if you replace it with a stack instead. Consider this example:

```
vector<int> A = { 4,2,1,3 };
vector<int> B = { 1,0,1,0 };
```

With a stack: 0 eats 1, 3 eats 2 and then 0 eats 3.

With your queue: 0 eats 1, 0 eats 3 and 2 cannot be eaten anymore.

Note: A queue works first in first out. On the otherhand a stack is last in first out. And thats what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post some algorithm thoughts and ideas for you.  Hopefully this will help you visual the problem.

Some initial observations - all fish swimming upstream at the beginning of the array can never eat or be eaten.  Same for fish at the bottom of the array swimming downstream.  The action occur when scanning from front to back when a downstream meets an up.

First, walk your array front to back until you find a down swimming fish.

Next continue walking your down/up array until it swaps from down to up.

Resolve combat and increment a combat counter.

If down wins, keep walking down.  If up wins, save the index of your location in the array(s), then walk it up the array until it is eaten or you hit a fish swimming the same direction.

If it finds a fish swimming its direction, it will live, jump back to where it started scan downwards again.

If it is eaten, take this fish and start comparing where you left off in the down array.

Repeat until you reach the end of the list.  Return the (starting number of fish - number of combats)

The neat part is this is in-place.  No moving of memory, no need to mark dead fish, etc.  It will run linear time - at most nearly 2x linear.

This the the pseudo code I would use to resolve this.

Comment: Hi, that's a nice an intuitive way to approach this problem, however when I tried to implement it, it was difficult to keep track of nested loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (admittedly moderately convoluted) solution:

```
// you can use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <stack>

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {
    list<int> fish;
    stack<int> upstream;
    for (int ii = A.size() - 1; ii >= 0; --ii) {
        if (B[ii] == 0)
            upstream.push(A[ii]);
        else {
            fish.push_back(A[ii]);
            while ( !upstream.empty() ) {
                if ( upstream.top() > fish.back() ) {
                    fish.pop_back();
                    fish.push_back( upstream.top() );
                    upstream.pop();
                    --ii;
                    if (ii < 0) {
                        ++ii;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        while (!fish.empty() && ii < (int) B.size()) {
                            if (B[ii] == 0) {
                                upstream.push(fish.back());
                                fish.pop_back();
                                ++ii;
                                break;
                            }
                            if ( fish.back() > A[ii] )
                                --ii;
                            else {
                                ++ii;
                                fish.pop_back();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } else
                    upstream.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    int add_size = 0;
    if ( !upstream.empty() )
        add_size = upstream.size();

    return fish.size() + add_size;
}
```

Algorithm:

- Input vector of fish sizes `A` gets traversed.
- Solution above assigns upstream swimming fish to a stack.
- When fish `ii` is swimming downstream (`B[ii] = 0`), it gets compared with fish in the `upstream` stack.
- If fish in the stack wins the comparison, it replaces fish `ii` in the list solution (that I have unimaginatively named `fish`), but it does not get popped from the `upstream` stack.
- Only if a fish in the stack is beaten, then it gets popped from the stack.
- After input has been traversed, return sum of survivors in the list and in the stack.

This passes the test proposed by @xeed and obtains overall 100% on Codility.
For a complete MWE, here is a driver main testing program:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> A = {4,3,2,1,5};
    vector<int> B = {0,1,0,0,0};
    int sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {4,3,2,1,5}, B = {0,1,0,0,0}? 2: " << sol << endl;

    A = {1,0};
    B = {1,0};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {1,0}, B = {1,0}? 1: " << sol << endl;

    A = {0,1};
    B = {0,0};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {0,1}, B = {0,0}? 2: " << sol << endl;

    A = {0};
    B = {1};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {0}, B = {1}? 1: " << sol << endl;

    A = {1};
    B = {0};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {1}, B = {0}? 1: " << sol << endl;

    A = {7,4,3,2,5,6};
    B = {0,1,1,1,0,1};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {7,4,3,2,5,6}, B = {0,1,1,1,0,1}? 3: " << sol << endl;

    A = {3,4,2,1,5};
    B = {1,0,0,0,0};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {3,4,2,1,5}, B = {1,0,0,0,0}? 4: " << sol << endl;

    A = {1,2};
    B = {0,1};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {1,2}, B = {0,1}? 2: " << sol << endl;

    A = {4,2,1,3};
    B = {1,0,1,0};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {4,2,1,3}, B = {1,0,1,0}? 1: " << sol << endl;

    A = {4,3,2,5,6};
    B = {1,0,1,0,1};
    sol = solution(A, B);
    cout << "A = {4,3,2,5,6}, B = {1,0,1,0,1}? 2: " << sol << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I wrote taking your testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> fishSize = { 4, 3, 2, 1, 5 };
    std::vector<int> fishDirection = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    
    int numberOfFish = fishSize.size();
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfFish; i++) {
        int curFishSize = fishSize[i];
        int curFishDirection = fishDirection[i];
        if (curFishDirection == 0) {
            // Direction down
            for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                int compareFishSize = fishSize[j];
                int compareFishDirection = fishDirection[j];
                if (compareFishDirection == 1 && compareFishSize < curFishSize) {
                    // Eat this fish
                    fishSize[j] = -1;
                    fishDirection[j] = -1;
                    std::cout << "Direction Down: Eating Fish " << j << " by " << i << std::endl;
                } else if (compareFishDirection == -1) {
                    continue;
                    
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        } else if (curFishDirection == 1) {
            // Direction up
            for (int j = i+1; j < numberOfFish; j++) {
                int compareFishSize = fishSize[j];
                int compareFishDirection = fishDirection[j];
                if (compareFishDirection == 0 && compareFishSize < curFishSize) {
                    // Eat this fish
                    std::cout << "Direction Up: Eating Fish " << j << " by " << i << std::endl;
                    fishSize[j] = -1;
                    fishDirection[j] = -1;
                } else if (compareFishDirection == -1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    int numberOfFishRemaining = 0;
    for(int a : fishSize) {
        if (a != -1) numberOfFishRemaining++;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Number Of Fish Remaining are: " << numberOfFishRemaining << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This solution will generate following output:

```
Direction Up: Eating Fish 2 by 1                                                                                                                     
Direction Up: Eating Fish 3 by 1                                                                                                                     
Direction Down: Eating Fish 1 by 4                                                                                                                   
Number Of Fish Remaining are: 2
```

I hope this also solves all your testcases.